# Determining which element has focus

Tags: javascript, dom-events

> **Possible Duplicates:**
> [How to determine which html page element has focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483741/how-to-determine-which-html-page-element-has-focus)
> [How do I find out which Javascript element has focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497094/how-do-i-find-out-which-javascript-element-has-focus)

Is there a way to determine which element within the document currently has focus?  Ideally without having to walk through every element.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Duplicate:

- [How to determine which html page element has focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483741/how-to-determine-which-html-page-element-has-focus)
- [How do I find out which Javascript element has focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497094/how-do-i-find-out-which-javascript-element-has-focus)

Long story short:

Some browsers (originally only IE, but Firefox 3 and Safari jumped on the wagon) support the `document.activeElement` property, which achieves what you want.

For older browsers, you need this hack to emulate the property:

```
function _dom_trackActiveElement(evt) {
    if (evt && evt.target) { 
        document.activeElement = evt.target == document ? null : evt.target;
    }
}

function _dom_trackActiveElementLost(evt) { 
    document.activeElement = null;
}

if (!document.activeElement) {
    document.addEventListener("focus",_dom_trackActiveElement,true);
    document.addEventListener("blur",_dom_trackActiveElementLost,true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could attach onfocus to your body element, and let the focus change event bubble up