# Find if a textbox is currently selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, focus

How would I find if a textbox (or textarea) currently is in focus? I don't care to know which one it is, I just need to know if one is in focus (has the cursor in it). How would I do this with javascript and jquery?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since you have found `document.activeElement`, you can check its nodeName.

```
if (document.activeElement.nodeName == 'TEXTAREA' || document.activeElement.nodeName == 'INPUT') {
    // ....
}
```

Something like that.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I get the jQuery object from document.activeElement?

Comment: This does not check for editable HTMLDivElements. See my answer below.

Answer (score 8):

Ok, just figured it out. Here's what I did:

```
function checkFocus() {

  if ($(document.activeElement).attr("type") == "text" || $(document.activeElement).attr("type") == "textarea") {

  //Something's selected

  return true;

 }

}
```

Comment: Someone mark this as the answer, it says I have to wait 2 days. :)

Comment: you're the only one who *can* mark this as the answer. Also, take a look at the [Stack Overflow Markdown help-page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/), for guidance on how to format your answers, particularly code samples.

Comment: Note that this will work on all modern browsers, but it will *not* work on many outdated browsers.  Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009777/determining-which-element-has-focus/1009787#1009787) for a technique to overcome this.

Answer (score 3):

Extending the accepted answer by a check for editable HTMLDivElements:

```
if (document.activeElement.nodeName == 'TEXTAREA'
    || document.activeElement.nodeName == 'INPUT'
    || (document.activeElement.nodeName == 'DIV'
        && document.activeElement.isContentEditable)) {
    // …
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#yourTextAreaID:focus');
```

would not work. :)  But

```
$('#yourTextAreaID').focus(function(){
    // do something
});
```

would excecute the `//do something` code when the element receives focus.

Comment: Ok, but at any given time (not neccesarily when the user clicks a textbox) how would I check if any textbox has focus?

Comment: Given that the OP doesn't care "which one it is," I'd suggest amending the selector to: `$('textarea:focus, input:text:focus')...`

Comment: I just found document.activeElement. How would I check if that is a textbox or textarea?

Comment: @David Thanks, that's cleaner.

Comment: I don't recognise the `:focus` pseudo-selector, and nor does the API or a quick test...

Comment: @lonesomeday, interesting catch: since it works under CSS I'd never thought to question whether or not it worked under jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#target').focus(function() {
  alert('Handler for .focus() called.');
});
```

**Also Try:**

```
alert($("*:focus").attr("id"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4KVvV/

Comment: as @lonesome pointed out above, :hover is not a real jquery selector.  I thought it was too, but when I checked the documentation, I couldn't find it mentioned.