# Is it possible to use a JavaScript onkeydown command only when a textbox is not selected?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a textbox

`<input type="text" id="textInput">`

with the following JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  alert('Key Pressed');
});
```

Would it be possible to trigger the alert only when the input is not selected?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575266/find-if-a-textbox-is-currently-selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for event target and then trigger the command.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if (!event === document.querySelector("#textInput")) {
        alert('Key Pressed');
    }
});
```

Hope This Helps !

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, check `document.activeElement` to see which element has focus:

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (document.activeElement && document.activeElement.id !== 'textInput'){
    alert('Key Pressed');
  }
});
```