# Find Which asp.net Component has Focus

Tags: .net, asp.net

Is there any way to find out which asp.net component has focus by using a server or client script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to determine which html page element has focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483741/how-to-determine-which-html-page-element-has-focus)

Answer (score 2):

Definitely not using a server script.  It's very important to understand that your server code does not run on an "active" page.  ASP.Net Server code only prepares html to send to the browser *before* the user sees it — even on a post back it's recreating the entire html page from scratch.

Client javascript is another story: you can handle the `onfocus` event for any element you care about.

Answer (score 0):

[How do I find out which Javascript element has focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497094/how-do-i-find-out-which-javascript-element-has-focus)

If the requirement is for IE only you can use

```
document.activeElement
```