# Check if an object has focus

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, javascript, visual-studio

How can I tell if a certain textbox has focus or not? I'm writing in C# in .NET.

Comment: duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483741/how-to-determine-which-html-page-element-has-focus

Comment: The 'javascript' tag might be a mistake, but this is not a duplicate of the above question IMHO.

Comment: redglyph: Check the edit history, he originally said "I'm using javascript writing in C#.NET"

Comment: Alright, thanks for pointing that out, it was confusing. And apparently now it's Javascript anyway from the last comment, ah well ;)

Answer (score 4):

You would have to use the javascript events `OnFocus` and `OnBlur`, and set a variable of some sort.  Basically:

```
<script>
   var lastFocus=null;

    function DoesControlHaveFocus(var control){return control==lastFocus;}
</script>
<input type="text" onfocus="lastFocus=this" onblur="lastFocus=null"/>
```

FOR A version that would work in the code-behind, you would set a hidden field to the ID of the control in the OnFocus command, which you could then check.

Comment: I think this will be my answer. I didn't get a chance to try it though but it seems right. +1 to you.

Answer (score 3):

Because performance can be a problem with generic solutions, the easiest thing I've come across so far is as follows:

1. Subscribe to the onFocus event of each control you care about.
2. In the onFocus handler, set a global variable (maybe "lastFocusElement") to the element that just received focus.
3. When you need to know that a certain control has focus, compare against the "lastFocusElement" variable.

Comment: Here, for C#, I have the `Enter` event actually, not onFocus (and the OnEnter Method). But that's the idea, I usually do that when I need to keep track of the focused element and it works fine.