# jQuery 1.4.2: .is(":focus") gives syntax error

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.4

Assume there is a document with a single input. What I'm trying to do is as simple as this:

```
$("input").focus().is(":focus");
```

I would expect the above code to return `true`. Instead, firebug logs an error:

```
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: focus
```

What am I missing here? I assumed that the syntax used with `is()` is identical to `$()`, or I can't do that?

How would you recommend to check for a focused input if this is unfixable instead?

**EDIT:**

As of jquery 1.6, the `:focus` selector is part of jquery core: http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/
If you need it, just upgrade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$("input").focus()` should suffice. As `:focus` is not a selector.

```
  $("input").focus(function () {
         //do something
    });
```

Edit:

`$("input:focus").runFunc();` I suppose that *might* work. [Cletus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683742/is-there-a-has-focus-in-javascript-or-jquery/2683838#2683838) has summed up this problem well I think, its worth a look.

Comment: This was just the most concise example I could think of to reproduce the error I'm having: `.is(":focus")` does not work. I'm not trying to `.focus()` an input, I'm trying to check if it's focused instead.

Comment: Do you plan on triggering an event once its focused? As my second function will be able to do so.. just replace the comment with the event...

Comment: Also, you say that `:focus` is not a selector. How come that `$(":focus")` **does** correctly select the focused inputs then?

Comment: According to the selectors list on http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ `:focus` is not a selector.

Comment: Follow the link I have posted above.

Answer (score 5):

You can test if it's the active (focused) element bu using [`document.activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.activeElement) like this:

```
if($("input")[0] == document.activeElement) {
  //first input is focused
}
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/nHfnR/).  Note though that most of the time your actions are triggered on another element, so if say you clicked a button then *it* would have focus and now be the active element, so you couldn't check this with a button check, because the element's already changed by the time your event fired, in most cases.

Comment: +1, this would be the quickest solution even if I'll go with the one Russell linked, so that I can have the `:focus` selector - more jqueryish :)

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your code and it will work:

```
jQuery.expr[':'].focus = function( elem ) {
  return elem === document.activeElement && ( elem.type || elem.href );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) function to do something like that.

```
$('input').focus(function () {
    $(this).data('focus', true); // set focus to true (on focus)
});
$('input').blur(function () {
    $(this).data('focus', false); // set focus to false (on blur)
});
```

Then to check for the focus use `$('#element-id').data('focus')`. If this is set to true, the element has the focus.

Answer (score 0):

do something like this instead:

`$('input').focus(function(){$(this).addClass('focus')});`

you can then check if an element has focus like this:

`$('input').hasClass('focus'); // this will return true or false`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check wether an input has focus or not you can use:

```
$('input:focus') //returns the focused element, assuming it's an input element...

$('[selector]:focus').length == 0 //check if a selected element has focus...
```