# jQuery: find which textbox has caret/is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a page with several text inputs and several buttons. When I click a button I want the value of that button to be inserted at the caret, whichever field the caret is in. Here's my function call so far:

```
$('li input[type="button"]').click(function(){$('#aTextInput').insertAtCaret($(this).val())});
```

I want to replace `$('#aTextInput')` with the input that actually has the caret in it. Any ideas?

([Here's](http://www.scottklarr.com/topic/425/how-to-insert-text-into-a-textarea-where-the-cursor-is/) the `insertAtCaret` function, before anyone asks. You probably **don't** need to look at it unless you're curious.)

**Edit:**

So I tried this:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {
    focus: "a == document.activeElement"
});

$('li input[type="button"]').click(function(){$('input:focus').insertAtCaret($(this).val())});
```

But when I click a button, nothing happens at all. Am I implementing [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683742/is-there-a-has-focus-in-javascript-or-jquery/2683838#2683838) wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683742/is-there-a-has-focus-in-javascript-or-jquery/2683838#2683838

Comment: I'd already seen that, but I can't get it to work. I'll edit my question to show how I tried to implement it--maybe I'm just doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have several textareas, you'd probably want to do something like this.

```
// any time a textarea gets focus, set the ID
$('textarea').focus(function(){
   focusID = $(this).attr('id');
});

// when the button is clicked
$('input[type="button"]').click(function(){    
    // insert the value into the textarea
    insertAtCaret(focusID,$(this).val())
});
```

[Check out my example on jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/FadEZ/1/)

The problem I had was, when the button is clicked the textarea loses focus, so it was hard to find the textarea that had focus at the moment the button was clicked.

**EDIT**

I just realized you were trying to do this with inputs, new jsFiddle here: [http://jsfiddle.net/tVNDL/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/tVNDL/4/)

```
// any time a input gets focus, set the ID
$('input').focus(function(){
   focusID = $(this).attr('id');
});

// when the button is clicked
$('input[type="button"]').click(function(){    
    // insert the value into the textarea
    insertAtCaret(focusID,$(this).val())
});
```

Comment: You bet, glad I could help! :-)