# Jquery IsFocus result different for safari and Other browsers

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery code like:

```
alert(!$('#txtSearchTextBox').is(":focus"));
```

Now the safari shows the message true and the other browsers show the message false when i write in the textbox.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683742/is-there-a-has-focus-in-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: @Hexxagonal I don't think it is. This question describes a specific issue with a specific browser. The question you linked to predates the `:focus` selector and is no longer accurate.

Comment: I didn't realize that was added in 1.6 and up. Cool.

Comment: @Hexxagonal I am using jquery 1.7+ and it has a focus selector. Check this link too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967096/using-jquery-to-test-if-an-input-has-focus. And please read the question before commenting it as duplicate

Comment: Yeah, I did. That's why I linked to something that creates an is(":focus") implementation and then afterward said I didn't realize that was added in 1.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ApQdD/1/) I tested it as working in Internet Explorer 9.

Looking at the jQuery bugs, I found that there is a [jQuery or Chrome bug which causes it to fail on that platform](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10569).  Testing in my version of Chrome it also fails.

I did not test with FireFox as the jQuery bug stated it worked there. And you already said it works for Safari.  I'm guessing your "other browsers" was Chrome.

Comment: It is not working for safari as the code alert(!$('#txtSearchTextBox').is(":focus")); must return false but it is returing false so problem is with safari and not others and chrome is working fine