# Passing String as parameter into jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, parameters

I'm having a strange jQuery issue. I'm writing a function that accepts a string as a parameter, and then am feeding that string into a jQuery selector.

Here is the function:

```
function myFunction(specialfields) {
   if(!$(specialfields).is(':focus')) {
       alert('thats not in focus');
   }
 }
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
 Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: focus
```

What's strange though is that the '.is(':focus') ' works in other areas, when not accepting a parameter, and if I pass this:

```
 $(specialfields)
```

It does read as valid object. I am trying to pass a string like this:

```
#id1, #id2
```

In addition, this works:

```
$(specialfields).val()
```

Anyone have any idea whats going here?

Comment: BTW, you're using `selector` as the argument name, but passing `specialfields` to jQuery.

Comment: Apologies, typo in my example!

Comment: just do a `console.log` and figure it out

Comment: What exactly is the value of the "specialfields" variable?

Comment: I believe I found the issue -- I was passing two varibles as specialfields "#id1, #id2". That may be breaking the focus

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I believe the issue was the fact I was passing two parameters into "specialfields", which broke the ':focus' selector as obviously you can't have two fields in focus at the same time.

It can be fixed by passing just a single selector in the function.

Answer (score 1):

## Conclusion

Your way worked all along and works faster than my waste-of-time alternative.

---

## Detail

I defined the function a little differently, and I replaced the `alert()` functionality by passing the response to a `<p id="response">`.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="id1" id="id1" />
<br />
<input type="text" name="id2" id="id2" />
<br />
<p id="response">response</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
var myFunction = function (specialfields) {
  if ($(specialfields + ':focus').length === 0) {
    $('#response').text(specialfields + ' is not in focus');
  } else {
    $('#response').text(specialfields + ' is in focus');
  }
};
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/UufWD/ for a working example.

You'll notice I evaluate the passed-in parameter for `:focus` with `if ($(specialfields + ':focus').length === 0)`.

### I thought this would be faster, but [that is not the case](http://jsperf.com/focus-length-vs-is-focus).

On the plus side, this method does handle multiple selector arguments (such as `#id1, #id2')`; see http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/UufWD/19/). But your original evaluation of `if(!$(specialfields).is(':focus'))` is better.

---

Now see http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/UufWD/14/ for a working example of your approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
I think .focus() should be enough, as :focus is not a selector.
```

There is no native solution but yes there is a more elegant way you can do it:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {
  focus: "a == document.activeElement"
});
```

You're defining a new selector. See Plugins/Authoring. Then you can do:

```
if ($("...").is(":focus")) {
  ...
}
```

Source--
[Is there a 'has focus' in JavaScript (or jQuery)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683742/is-there-a-has-focus-in-javascript-or-jquery/2683838#2683838)

Comment: jQuery 1.6 added `:focus`.