# Prevent from reactivating javascript blind effect on password fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I have this project im working on and i have two password fields when each one gains focus it use a jquery show blind effect; that displays a password strength div below the password fields. Then when it lose focus it hides the password strength div. I want the password strength to remain open when i switch between both password fields.

```
$('input[type=password]').focus(function() {
$('#pswd_info').show("blind", { direction: "vertical" }, 1000);
    }).blur(function() {
       $('#pswd_info').hide("blind", { direction: "vertical" }, 1000);
    });
```

***edited:***

So i have spend some time trying to figure this out but i have. Here is my solution THANKS to Robert. Here is my solution.

```
$('input[type=password]').focus(function() {
            $('#pswd_info').show("blind", { direction: "vertical" }, 300);
        });

 $("input[type=password]").blur(function() {
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                if($(":focus").attr("type") != "password"){
                    $('#pswd_info').hide("blind", { direction: "vertical" }, 300);
                }
            },100);
        });
```

thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Then you have to remove the `hide` from the blur function.  Right?

Comment: If i do that it wont hide the `#pswd_info` div when the password fields lose focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `document.ActiveElement` and see if it's one of your two password fields.  If it isn't, you can allow the `.hide` function to execute.

More info here: [Is there a 'has focus' in JavaScript (or jQuery)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683742/is-there-a-has-focus-in-javascript-or-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried like this ... it just a suggestion ....

```
$('input[type=password]').live('keyup',function() {
$('#pswd_info').show("blind", { direction: "vertical" }, 1000);
    }).blur(function() {
       $('#pswd_info').hide("blind", { direction: "vertical" }, 1000);
    });
```

Comment: Yeah it didn't work. Unless I'm not using it in the right places