# Get text input element having cursor (caret) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How to Get the text element (or its id) in which there is caret?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine which html page element has focus?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483741/how-to-determine-which-html-page-element-has-focus)

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Guess, I completely misunderstood the word "caret" as it stands for "cursor" in this context... not a native speaker. In case someone looks for a way to find the input which has the "^" character in its value:

Try [this plain JavaScript code on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/De2PT/):

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var ids = [];
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if(inputs[i].value.match(/.*\^.*/)) {
      ids.push(inputs[i].id);
    }
}
```

It goes through all "input" elements and filters out those with a caret somewhere in their value. "ids" holds those ids.

Answer (score 3):

`document.activeElement` will give you this in most browsers.

Answer (score 1):

if you mean how to get text box having focus the answer is you can't.

You could script to "onfocus" event, and record the last-focused field in a variable somewhere. 
You also have to use "onblur" event to clear last-focused field variable.

HTH

Ivo Stoykov

Comment: How to determine which html page element has focus?

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
var elementWithFocus;

function updateFocus(callingElement)
{
    elementWithFocus = callingElement;
}
```

Then in your inputs:

```
<input onfocus="updateFocus(this);" onblur="updateFocus(null);"></input>
```

Play around with it [on jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/H2FG8/).