# get id of focused element using javascript

Tags: javascript, focus

I have single Html page having many anchor elements. This single Html page contains many div parts. Only one part displays at time and a anchor specific to this part will focused. this html also contain a div to open popup. When this popup will open anchor specific to this will focused. Now I want get the anchor focused earlier to popup anchor focused.
My code is following:-

```
<body onload="Main.onLoad();" onunload="Main.onUnload();">

        <a href='javascript:void(0);' id='anchor' onkeydown='Main.MainKeyHandler();'></a>
        <a href='javascript:void(0);' id='anchorAboutUs' onkeydown='Main.MainKeyHandler1();'></a>
        <a href='javascript:void(0);' id='anchorSecondScreen' onkeydown='Main.MainKeyHandler2();'></a>
        <a href='javascript:void(0);' id='popupanchor' onkeydown='PopupKeyHandler();'></a>
        <div id="ParentDiv">
            <div id="SplashScreenDiv">
                <div id="SplashScreen"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="Logo"></div>
            <div id="Header"></div>
            <div  id='messagePopup'  style='position:relative;width:500px;z-index:1000;background-color:#ffffff;'><div ></div ><div id='popupReturn'>Return</div><div>
            <div id="PopUp">
                <div id="YesBtn"></div>
                <div id="NoBtn"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="FirstScreen">
            <div id="testinfo" style="color:#ff0000; width:600px; height:50px; overflow:hidden; font-size:xx-large; "></div>
                <div id="btn_horoscope"></div>
                <div id="btn_aboutus"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="AboutUsScreen" >
                <div id="AboutUsImgDiv">
                    <div id="AboutUsImg"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="aboutUsInfoDiv">
                    <div id="aboutUsInfo"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="SecondScreen" >
                <div id="HoroscopeImg" class="HoroImage"></div>
                <div id="SelSunSignMsgDiv">
                    <div id="SelSunSignMsg">Select your SunSign </div>
                </div>
                <div id="SelSunSignDiv">
                    <div id="SelSunSign">
                    <div id="SunSign_0"></div>
                    <div id="SunSign_1"></div>
                    <div id="SunSign_2"></div>
                    <div id="SunSign_3"></div>
                    <div id="SunSign_4"></div>
                    <div id="SunSign_5"></div>
                    <div id="SunSign_6"></div>
                    <div id="SunSign_7"></div>
                    <div id="SunSign_8"></div>
                    <div id="SunSign_9"></div>
                    <div id="SunSign_10"></div>
                    <div id="SunSign_11"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>


    </body>
```

any help will appriciated

Comment: As this is a javascript question, your js code would be more interesting

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483741/how-to-determine-which-html-page-element-has-focus

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find out which DOM element has the focus?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497094/how-do-i-find-out-which-dom-element-has-the-focus)

Answer (score 24):

You need `document.activeElement.id`. You can find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/497108/430408), which has been criticized before.