# Detect element ISN'T selected

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How can I test if a HTML element is focused? I want to execute a code when a dropdown select list ISN'T selected. So, If you click on the document, anywhere else in than the select list, a JavaScript unselect all of it's elements.

This statement doesn't worked:

```
var items=document.getElementById("items");
items.focused==false;
```

I hope somebody can help me out.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but very close: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483741/how-to-determine-which-html-page-element-has-focus

Comment: You can use the event `onblur`, which gets called when something looses focus

Comment: Check if the item is `=== document.activeElement`

Comment: What do you mean by `a dropdown select list ISN'T selected`? Because by default the first `option` in the `select`-list gets selected even if it is not provided the `selected` property. So would you please elaborate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Newer versions of JavaScript allow this:

```
if( items.matchesSelector(":focus"))
```

But for older browsers you can try:

```
if( document.querySelector("#items:focus"))
```

However this won't work in IE 7 and older.

If you require support for these, then I would suggest something like this for your handler:

```
// some means of attaching a handler(evt) {
evt = evt || window.event;
var target = evt.srcElement || evt.target;
while(target) {
    if( target.id == "items") return true;
    target = target.parentNode;
}
// #items is not the target. Do something.
```